# Native client - access downloaded file in sandbox

Tags: google-chrome, file-io, sandbox, google-nativeclient

I wrote a small module that just opens a file in the local filesystem, and writes some dummy bytes to it.

Is it possible to access this file on the users computer? Where can I find it? In other words: Can the user (manually) get anything out of the native client modules sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

You can transmit file to javascript and save it from there with HTML5 File API. The page http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/ gives an example:

```
var bb = new WebKitBlobBuilder(); // adapted for chrome
bb.append("Lorem ipsum");
var fileSaver = window.saveAs(bb.getBlob(), "test_file");
fileSaver.onwriteend = myOnWriteEnd;
```

Comment: Actually, my native client app is meant to receive data/file info/contents from javascript, and then store to disk using the pepper api. can I access those files?

Comment: Sending file back to javascript will be more user-friendly (although this do could defeat the purpose of NaCl). I don't know HTML5 file storage format on disk yet.

Comment: Sending file to javascript and saving it with code above should work.

Comment: Yes but I was asking if it was possible to access the filesystem of the native client sandbox